# Dragon shouts - how to find locations in-game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am confused. How am I supposed to find out the Words' location in the world (not using internet)?
Say I want to complete my **Fire Breath** shout, what am I supposed to do?

And also, do multiple shouts share some words? I don't even know which exist, but say, is *Fus* used in other shoults than Unrelenting Force? *(If not, it kinda sucks)*

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time you will find shouts during quests; couriers will deliver messages to you revealing shout locations, Sometimes the shout will be in the area the quest takes place. Just keep an eye out.

If you don't mind soiling your experience (imo) you can [look up](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/Shout_Locations) the locations for shout words online and attain them that way.

As for part two of your question, I'm pretty sure all shouts have unique words they use. So no, words are only used once.

Answer (score 10):

Two ways to find dragon shouts are to use your current dragon shouts in a town until a courier will come along giving you a letter which will lead you to another word wall, keep in mind, you can only have one letter at a time, you need to find the current word wall before a courier will deliver a new note.

The second way is to talk to Arngeir (who you will meet along the main storyline) and he will direct you to a word wall that you haven't found yet. Just like with the couriers, you can only have one quest from Arngeir at a time.

The two quests aren't mutually exclusive though, and you can have one of each at a time, giving you two word walls at a time to find.

Comment: You trailed off a bit, there.  ;-)

Comment: @BenBlank My net was down when I first wrote this, I guess when I tried to resubmit it, it cut the end off, will edit it with the rest of the info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes words can be used in different shouts. For example, if you have the dark brotherhood shout **Marked For Death** (who's first word is ***KILL***). Talk to the steward of Riften and she will tell you of a dragon attacking autumnwatch tower who has a bounty out for it. There you will find a dragon and a word wall with the word for ***LEECH***. It will add on to marked for death and is the second word in a health leeching shout I believe which you then get the first word of that shout for free ;). spending a dragon soul on either shout will unlock the word ***LEECH*** if used in a shout so 1 word for 2 shouts = 1 dragon soul or Dragon Souls don't unlock shouts, they unlock words for shouts. Also I noticed that if there is a mountain, there is almost always a dragon nest at the peak. Also If there is a dragon, There is usually a nest. Most if not All nests have word walls. Furthermore I've found that Ruins where Dragon Priests Reside have Word Walls, Morokei has 1 which If I remember is **Slow Time**, and Hevnoraak has **Aura Whisper** which detects the aura of the living (even Draugr who are still asleep but will wake up to kill you). Hevnoraak and Morokei are the only 2 I have killed.