# Where's the last word for the shout Slow Time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking for the last word to Slow Time. I want to know where it is. Can you tell me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dragon shouts - how to find locations in-game?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37241/dragon-shouts-how-to-find-locations-in-game)

Answer (score 13):

All words are located in the following locations:

- [Hag's End](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hag%27s_End): Found before the fourth round of battle with the Hagraven,
- [Korvanjund](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Korvanjund): You must have started The Jagged Crown quest in order to enter, and
- [Labyrinthian](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Labyrinthian): You can't enter until you're almost done the College of Winterhold questline

The *last word* is the one you didn't find, as they are unlocked in order.

Comment: Note that both Korvanjund and Labyrinthian are locked and can only be accessed if you are on a quest that takes you there.

Comment: The walls are not, in fact, unlocked in any set order -- my mage character has learned the word from Labyrinthian, but has never been to Hag's End, nor started The Jagged Crown. Words are always learned in order, though, regardless of the order in which you visit the walls. Therefore the wall @Braden still needs to find could be any of those three.

Answer (score 9):

Since the words strictly follow the order in which they're found, it could be in one of three places (depending on which ones you've already unlocked), these places according to the [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shout):

- Labyrinthian (Quest locked)
- Hag's End
- Korvanjund (Quest locked)

What it means by "Quest locked" is that you can not learn the word unless you are on, or *have finished* the quest for their respective locations.